# Rails wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this condition in my view:

```
if current_employee.admin? && !current_employee(employee)
```

And i have a boolean `admin` field in my db.  If the value of boolean admin is 0, everything works fine. If it's 1 , it throws this error.

What could be the cause if this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the first part, but the second part. This part only gets run when the admin boolean is 1. So you should check this:

```
current_employee(employee)
```

Your method only expects one argument. So perhaps you should try changing:

```
def current_employee
```

To:

```
def current_employee(employee)
```

Or remove the employee argument from the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `employee` from your current_employee call.

Comment: then the issue is with current_employee. Remove the parameter `employee`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your model, try:

`if current_employee.admin? && !current_employee.employee`